# How to avoid do loop for switching matrix index in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I would like to know if it is possible to reproduce the following MWE without the do loops.
Of course, in this simplistic example I can do it manually to avoid the do loop since the matrices `MatA`, `MatBx` and `MatBy` are only 2 by 2, but in my real cases matrices can be much larger.

```
PROGRAM MAIN 

   implicit none
   real, dimension(2,2) :: MatA
   integer, dimension(2,2) :: MatBx
   integer, dimension(2,2) :: MatBy
   real, dimension(2,2) :: MatC
   integer :: x,y


   MatC=0.

   MatA(1,1)=10
   MatA(1,2)=20
   MatA(2,1)=30
   MatA(2,2)=40

   MatBx(1,1)=1
   MatBx(1,2)=2
   MatBx(2,1)=1
   MatBx(2,2)=1

   MatBy(1,1)=1
   MatBy(1,2)=1
   MatBy(2,1)=2
   MatBy(2,2)=1

   Print*, MatA  

   do y=1,2
      do x=1,2
         MatC(x,y)= MatA(MatBx(x,y), MatBy(x,y))      
      enddo
   enddo

   Print*, MatC

END PROGRAM MAIN
```

Executed with the command:

```
user$ gfortran -o progtest test.f90 && ./progtest 
   10.0000000       30.0000000       20.0000000       40.0000000    
   10.0000000       20.0000000       30.0000000       10.0000000
```

So I was wondering if it was possible to perform this kind of operation on the indexes for the whole matrix directly: something like `MatC(:,:)= MatA(MatBx(:,:), MatBy(:,:))` (which is not working).

## Precisions

Some precisions that might helping to understand the general case:

In the general case, the matrices can be NxM rather than 2x2.

The general operation is sending information from `MatA` to `MatC` according to a transfer matrix named `MatB`. All the elements of `MatA` are not necessary received by `MatC`: in the above example the element `MatA(2,2)` is not received by `MatC`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The generalisation could even be NxM. You are right, it does not tranpose if we look at MatC(2,2)=MatA(1,1). The operation in general is sending information from `MatA` to `MatC` but at different locations (not random localisations but almost, ie. according to a transfer matrix named `MatB`).

Comment: First, your nest-loops are accessing the matrices in a suboptimal way.  Second, and more importantly "Why?".  The do-loops are clear.  Any combination of `RESHAPE, SHAPE, PACK, MERGE` etc may appear elegant but is likely impenetrable to the programmer.

Comment: @evets Can you develop a bit more about this suboptimal access to the matrices ? About the why: I would like to try if this make my code faster.

Comment: Your striding through non-consecutive memory for `MatC(x,y)` on the LHS.  The RHS  non-consecutive memory is unavoidable.  I doubt that you find any other way in lieu of do-loops to make the code faster.  Fortran has been optimizing do-loop constructs for 60+ years.

Comment: @evets I am sorry I do not know really how is organized the memory, but why `MatC(x,y)` is not consecutive ? How can I improve it ? 
Thanks for your opinion about making the code faster (it is good to know for the final purpose). However, do you think that it is possible to avoid these do-loop ? and how exactly ?

Comment: Fortran is a column-major language.  `matc(1,1)` and `matc(2,1)` in consecutive memory locations.  Your access pattern is `matc(1,1)` then `matc(1,2)`.  This probably isn't too important for a 2x2 matrix, but for larger dimensions you'll be flushing the memory cache.

Comment: @evets Good to know. I edit the order of the loop my question according to these information.